# Declaring an AdView in XML

Tags: java, android, admob

I'm struggling to add some ads in my application and I'm systematically facing the error message that the adSize parameter is missing. My XML file is the following :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
android:id="@+id/Window"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".myApp">

<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
    android:id="@+id/adView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    ads:adUnitId="4sdfgsd5gs4df5g5sd"
    ads:adSize="BANNER"
    ads:testDevices="TEST_EMULATOR,4sdfgsd5gs4df5g5sd"
    ads:loadAdOnCreate="true"/>

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/Cont"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="top" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/Controls"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <mypackage.utils.myapp.view1
            android:id="@+id/title"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1">            
        </mypackage.utils.myapp.view1>

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/Lum"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:src="@drawable/my_drawable1"
            android:text="@string/Lum">            
        </ImageButton>

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/Photo"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:src="@drawable/my_drawable2"
            android:text="@string/Photo">           
        </ImageButton>

    </LinearLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

I have read answers to similar questions posted on this site but, so far, nothing prevented the error message from being triggered. All these actions didn't change anything :

- using `xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"` instead of `xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"`
  `
- using `xmlns:ads="xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.jms.AdmobExample"` instead of `xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"`
  `

I can add that I don't have any "Attrs.xml" files in my project but, as an answer reminds that it's not mandatory anymore with the new version of AdMob, this shouldn't be a problem.

What is wrong with my XML file?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you have in your activity, but as far as the XML goes, you should use:

```
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
```

Instead of:

```
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
```

And your AdView should look like this:

```
<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
android:id="@+id/adView"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
ads:adUnitId="4df1657304086fd7"
ads:adSize="BANNER" />
```

If this doesn't work, then add your activity so we can make sure that you have it all entered correctly as well. Also, make sure you are using the Google Play Services API.

*EDIT*
Add this to your Manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
```

Comment: Well, now, it seems to work, thanks. But is it normal that I only get a white rectangle for an ad? The code requesting for an ad is the following :        adView=(AdView)vue.findViewById(R.id.adView);
        request=new AdRequest.Builder()
         .addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR)
         .addTestDevice("4sdfgsd5gs4df5g5sd")
         .build();
        adView.loadAd(request);

Comment: Try removing the .addTestDevice for a quick test. For this to work you need your app to access the internet, check my original post for that.

Comment: The Internet permissions were already there. Removing the "addTestDevice" didn't help neither. One additional piece of information : in the logcat, I get the error (which doesn't lead to an application crash) : "The Google play services resources were not found. Check your project configuration to ensure that the resources are included". In my project, the Google play service is already registered in the Android section of my app's properties and the "google-play-services_lib.jar" file is included in my Java build path. Do I have anything else to configure?

Comment: Do you mind adding your activity to the original post so I can take a look?

Answer (score 0):

Adding a add is pretty simple just follow these steps:

Just paste this code in the activity.

// Create an ad.

```
private static final String AD_UNIT_ID = "****************************";

adView = new AdView(this);
adView.setAdSize(AdSize.BANNER);
adView.setAdUnitId(AD_UNIT_ID);

// Add the AdView to the view hierarchy. The view will have no size
// until the ad is loaded.
LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linearLayout);
layout.addView(adView);

// Create an ad request. Check logcat output for the hashed device ID to
// get test ads on a physical device.
AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
    .addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR)
    .addTestDevice("INSERT_YOUR_HASHED_DEVICE_ID_HERE")
    .build();

// Start loading the ad in the background.
adView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

The main thing to check is:
 LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linearLayout);

make sure you give the id of the layout of xml you are using for you activity.

Answer (score 0):

Create global variables

```
/** The view to show the ad. */
private AdView adView;
/* Your ad unit id. Replace with your actual ad unit id. */
private static final String AD_UNIT_ID = "YOUR_UNIT_ID";
```

in oncreate method of the activity

```
// Look up the AdView as a resource and load a request.
AdView adView = (AdView) this.findViewById(R.id.adView);
AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
adView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

in xml file

```
<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
android:id="@+id/adView"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
ads:adSize="BANNER"
ads:adUnitId="YOUR_UNIT_ID" />
```

the permissions in the androidManifest.xml file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
```